Python Intellisense on Visual Studio Code
I'm just starting to learn coding in Python and have just downloaded Visual Studio Code, however I cannot find Python Intellisense on the extensions marketplace. It's not there. Does it have an alternative name that I could be  missing?
I tried searching for it.

It's called Pylance with ID ms-python.vscode-pylance. It is also part of an extension pack called Python, that installs with 2 other extensions for Python development

Thank you so mach Ana for prompt response and assistance.
